# PHP: Is there a difference between use of ++ or +=1

Tags: php

When using increment on variables in Javascript, lint says that `x += 1` is preferred over `x ++`.

But what about in PHP?

Is there any difference between the `+=` and `++` or does it just not really matter?

Comment: Whichever feels easier to read; or as appropriate to the circumstances of your code

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well whatever you might say about conventions, try running the following...

```
$i = 1;  $s = 's';
$i++;    $s++;
echo $i.'<br>'.$s.'<br>';

$i = 1;   $s = 's';
$i += 1;  $s += 1;
echo $i.'<br>'.$s.'<br>';
```

the *output* is somewhat unexpected...

```
2
t
2
1
```

so I would say it could matter very much which is chosen!

Answer (score 2):

x += 1 is rather equivalent to ++x.

All those expressions (x += 1, x++ and ++x) increment the value of num by one, but the value of x++ is the value x had before it got incremented.

Comment: It does have different effects on strings though, as pointed out by Barry. But even this has quirks, once the string can be interpreted as float (`++"9E0"` will unexpectedly give you a float with value `10`): http://php.net/manual/de/language.operators.increment.php#109621